# Trouble with ActionScript 3, not working, and i have no idea why, flash CS4

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe, flash-cs4

I'm very new to ActionScript 3, and I've followed this toturial on adobe TV. But I don't get it to work. The thing is that I want the box to move left/right when I click the buttons, but nothing happens.

You can download the .fla file here:

http://www.habitats.no/files/AC3.zip

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your instances.  Click on one of the movie clips on the stage and bring up the properties window, you should see an input for `instance name`.  The way you've coded it the instance name should be the same as the clips name i.e. `mc_box`.

Answer (score 1):

You must to give your objects names, for example you have:

1. Button - you must to put the name for Button in panel properties of button - myBtn (the name of button in Instance name field) ;
2. Box - you must to put the name for Box in panel properties of Box (is movieClip) - myBox (the name of Box in Instance name field) ;

and write this code in actions:

```
myBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveBox);
function moveBox(event):void
{
    Box.x+=25;
}

// addEventListener - Registers an event listener for the target event.
```

When you call `AddEventListener ()` reported two parameters:

- An event which should respond to the application;
- A function which is a reaction to this event.